# Selecting a metric in training models using caret package in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, r-caret

As far as I know, caret has accuracy and kappa as metrics we can select. How can we train a model using F-1 Score? Let's say we are training a CART model. Any example would be appreciated

I also have imbalanced data (binary class where one class is 10% in the data). I am trying to balance between precision and recall as models tend to predict the other class. Should I consider F-1 score or Kappa or ROC? I thought F-1 score might be a better option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caret allows you to implement your own performance measures, so you could do it that way. An alternative would be to use the [mlr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr/index.html) package, which does implement F1 (and [many more measures](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/measures/index.html)). For example, to find the best values for `minsplit` and `minbucket` by F1 score you'd do something like the following.

```
library(mlr)

ps = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("minsplit", values = 1:20),
  makeDiscreteParam("minbucket", values = 1:10)
)
ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10)
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 10)
res = tuneParams("classif.rpart", measures = f1, task = sonar.task,
                 resampling = rdesc, par.set = ps, control = ctrl)
print(res$x)
print(res$y)
```

The mlr tutorial has [a whole section](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/over_and_undersampling/index.html) on imbalanced classification problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are much better off using the ROC curve so that you don't have to worry about the event threshold. For imbalanced data, many metrics that use the default 50% cutoff result in artificially skewed results. In `caret`, you  can use the `twoClassSummary` function